# Performance of RNN with long sequences in Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I have build an RNN which has a sequence length of about 10,000. It took very long time to create the optimizer
`train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.008).minimize(cost)` and took very long time to train. I am wondering how to expedite the computation process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version of TensorFlow (current nightly build/upcoming version 0.8) includes an experimental feature called [`tf.nn.dynamic_rnn()`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/51f5f6be3ede7242b01c4bdf136de938fd00839f/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn.py#L373). This function lets you build a RNN using a loop in the TensorFlow graph, which dramatically cuts the number of nodes used in the graph (and hence the size of the graph that must be built for gradient descent).